# Is it possible to upgrade with an SSD a laptop dual booted with ubuntu and windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a GS 66 MSi with a 500gb ssd with windows 10, I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu. I'm new to doing this sort of stuff so I'm not sure how to perform the dual booting but I have found very through guides already.

My issue comes in the following situation. After havign both OSs on my laptop, if I want to upgrade it with another ssd, how would this storage affect my laptop? would I be able to allocate half of the storage to each os?

Comment: Sure, you could allocate half of the storage to each OS. Or any fraction you wish.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer comes with a 'try Ubuntu' option.  This is for you to check for any hardware problems and to see if you like it.  The try Ubuntu will not keep any changes done to it after rebooting it.  Installing as a dual boot is easy to do, but it is also easy to make a mistake and loose all your data.  Backup is highly recommended, because we all make oops.

Answer (score 0):

Most computers and OSs can handle more than one drive.  Some people put one OS per drive or put all OSs on one drive and use the other for data storage.  Ubuntu/Linux does this easier because they don't really care what type of drive they are put on, unlike Windows that can get picky.  As long as all OSs are installed the same(legacy/MBR or UEFI/GPT) should be good.  Backup of data before installing OS is recommended.